# How do you run multiprocessing pool.starmap outside of __main__ function?

Tags: python, integration-testing, python-multiprocessing

All the documentation I have read mentioned that the Pool should be surrounded by a check that it's in main. Otherwise, there is potential for an infinite loop.

**What I see Online to Do:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
          output = pool.starmap(test_func, list(tuples))
```

However, I am running the multiprocessing library in a sub-module (not '**main**') and not having any errors (note running it thru a Juypter-notebook). I do have an infinite loop when trying to run some integration tests I made with the unittest library.

How can I run the multiprocessing step in a sub-module?

**How I am Currently Doing It:**

```
with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
     output = pool.starmap(test_func, list(tuples))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I run most of my code in a Jupyter notebook I have run into this same problem. From what I have read Jupyter has a problem with namespace/ memory when trying to run a function that is in the same notebook inside jupyter.

The fix for me was to place the function I wanted to run into a module.py file and import the function and run the pool that way. IDKY but that works when running in Jupyter.